# SSRS Reporting Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, split, region

I have an SSRS Report which reports on employee data which is gathered by the Report Query. There is a record for each day and employee selected.
I need this data not to be split over two pages.

I have set the detail group set to keep together. I have each line in the group set to keep together.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
It wont let me add images
[Keeptogether](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7l7z.jpg/%22keeptogether%22)
Examples of output
[Page9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLXl.jpg)
[Page10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRljr.jpg)

[Page12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisbQ.jpg)

Any help greatly appreciated. I have been googling my heart out... but nothing seems to have worked so far!
I've tried
- setting the detail group - keeptogether property on
- each detail line - keeptogether property on
- Rectangle that contains the Tablix -  keeptogether property on
- Report -interactive height 0
- Detail Group - Adding sorting options
- made sure there is no white space under the Tabix

Comment: You need to post your report design, details of groups and relevant properties and examples of output otherwise nobody can help you, there simply isn't enough information here. Also, explain what yo have tried so far as this will save anyone helping you repeating the same things you've already done.

Comment: i tried, but the photos didn't upload, I'll try again

Comment: Are we allowed to have a look at page 10?

Comment: It's there now.  had so much trouble uploading and saving these images!  Anyway there now... Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in SSRS:

1. On the layout tab, click the properties icon
2. choose report from the drop down list
3. expand the section interactive size
4. set the height to 0

Answer (score 0):

Put a tablix in your report and add your fields **Date, Registration and a Measure**. If you execute the report it gets shown like your picture **Page9**. Now click on **Row Groups** at your tablix, then **(Details) -> Add Group -> Parent Group** and choose your grouping, in your case by Date (optional you can check **Add  group header**. The Date value appears just once and is merged.

Comment: But my report has a tablix already? and the client wants the date for every employee

Comment: Its just an example. When you try it you will see how it works, then you can adapt it to your report and delete the created tablix.

Comment: OK that's weird , now they don't get split but the page has elongated to fit two days worth of records??

Comment: Yes thats because of the grouping. It is a workaround. Normally what @Programmermid said should work.